# When and how to save data to database in Android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-networking

I am trying to understand the best practice for getting data from server and storing it in database and showing it in fragments in a multi-tabbed android app

The app structure is as below : Main activity has 3 tabs, each of which has a list of feeds, friends, rewards respectively that are fetched from the server. These require hitting three diff endpoints, and are paged (each of feed,reward, friend info comes in page of size = 5)

Currently in App.onCreate() method [App extends Application], I am hitting the first pages of these end points and storing it in an App.appData object (a compound object that has ArrayList feeds, ArrayList friends, ArrayList reward).

Should I be saving these to database as well at the same time, or should I somehow intercept when the user has paused the app (i.e. no activities are visible) and in that callback function save the-then contents of App.appData into database? Otherwise I feel like once user scrolls through and goes to pages below this fetch from server and write to database cycle would be going on many time

Are there any best practices/tutorials for such application architecture?

```
+-----+----+---+                           
|  T1 | T2 | T3|                           
+-----+----+---+  +---------+   +---------+
|      F1      |  |  F2     |   |    F3   |
| +----------+ |  |         |   |         |
| +----------+ |  | +-------+   |  +----+ |
|              |  | |-------+   |  |----| |
|  +---------+ |  | |-----| |   |  |----| |
|  +---------+ |  | +-----+ |   |  +----+ |
|              |  |  Friends|   | Rewards |
|     Feeds    |  |         |   |         |
+--------------+  +---------+   +---------+
```

Comment: (Just me) I immediately persist data locally when it changes.

Comment: Thanks, and how are you doing it? In the sense that when the network request (I am doing via retrofit) fails, are you automatically picking up data from the DB table? Is there a library that streamlines this process (similar to caching basically)? Thanks

Comment: Persisting locally and syncing with a server are two totally different things.  Do not cache db changes.  Have isDirty, isDeleted bits in the local db table and on successful communication with server clear the isDirty bit and/or perform physical delete.  Data that is changed on the server and needs to be pushed to the app well that is beyond difficult to do as the server needs to know what is already on the device to efficiently push changes down.  Oh I've never used retrofit or volley because I didn't have a problem with the httpurlconnection in android.

Answer (score 3):

I work on app with a similar architecture. We fetch data from a server and store it in a database as it arrives. Our UI objects fetch what they need from the database. The nice thing about this architecture is that the UI is never directly dependent on the network -- it always just shows whatever is available in the database. However, there are a number of important questions that influence whether this type of architecture makes sense for you:

1. How often does the data you are fetching change? For example, if the user runs the app after a couple of days, would it be reasonable to show some old data while you check for newer stuff?
2. For how long is the data you fetch valid? If you fetch and store a lot of data one day, will it still be valid the next day, or would you need to throw it away? If old data is useless, then a database is less helpful.
3. How large are your lists of data? Do they go forever (e.g. search results of decreasing relevance), or is there an end (e.g. a list of Facebook friends)? If your lists go on forever, then storing the lists in a database becomes less helpful.

In my app, data never becomes invalid, the amount of new data each day is small, and the amount of data is not so large as to be difficult to manage in a database. This allows us to always have a good set of data for the UI to show. However, depending on your answers to those questions, a database might not be quite as useful.

Hope this is helpful. Sorry if I'm just rambling.

EDIT:
For the storage we're just using SQLiteDatabase and related classes. I've written a layer on top of that to keep most of the data in memory for better performance. When new data is received from the network, I can quickly check the memory map to see if something is new or updated, and then save it to the DB as needed.

I'm not sure you want to depend on App.onCreate as the main place to make requests. If your app is sitting in the background for a long time, but still running, then you may not realize that you should fetch new data. We use a base class for our fragments, and in onResume we fetch data from the DB (or the memory map) so that it is always fresh. You can also keep track of the last time you fetched data (keep a time stamp in SharedPreferences), and every 4 hours or so issue a new request.

The base fragment class is also a handy way to receive notification when new data is available. In onResume we register the fragment as active, and in onPause deregister it. Then when new data is available from the network, you just check which fragments are active, and notify them. Those fragments can then fetch data from the DB and refresh, the same way as when onResume is called.

Comment: that is exactly the kind of app I am making. Of the 3 fragments, one fragment is Feed, and new feeds come in every 3-4 hours (for that user); the Friend list changes once a day maybe and the Rewards list also changes once a day. Can I ask what packages are you using? I am using Retrofit - and I am thinking whats best wa to persist it? I am thinking making the network/server requests in the Application.onCreate() using Retrofit (async task) and then showing the data from database to the Fragments to populate their UI. How can I then re-communicate to UI once new data arrives from server

Comment: Here's a mini ramble.  The questions.  I sometimes enjoy the meetings these questions come up in sometimes not.  I sometimes drift off and dream about streamlining the answering of the questions or think about what if someone non technical gave an answer in miliseconds for the disposition of data.  I brought up the question because its an important decision.

Comment: @dowjones123 shouldn't feeds come in as they occur like the "new stories" button that pops up on social apps.

Comment: @danny117, yes, its just that our feeds are much lower in frequency